# FIrefox/Thunderbird storage locations

Tags: environment-variables, firefox, thunderbird

By default, Firefox and Thunderbird save their files to `~/.mozilla` and `~/.thunderbird`.

I am wondering if there's an environment variable I can set, to have either of them save their data to a different location. I want to have multiple instances of them available, each with their own settings for server and application testing. I can do this with the`-no-remote` option and Profile Manager of each, but I was wondering if I could totally keep the testing profiles separate from my `main` configuration.

This would also enable me to keep the profiles in source control if I so desired.

Comment: You could try `HOME=~/testing` and populate `~/testing/.mozilla`, but [since these are Gnome programs it apparently won't work](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14944/isnt-home-supposed-to-be-the-location-of-the-users-home-directory).

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. If I change $HOME, thunderbird respects the change. I start the new instance up with a script like

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDHOME=$HOME;
export HOME=/home/moo/work/test

mkdir $HOME/.mozilla $HOME/.thunderbird;
ln -s .mozilla mozilla;
ln -s .thunderbird thunderbird;

/usr/bin/thunderbird -no-remote;

export HOME=$OLDHOME;
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox and Thunderbird do not have a built-in method of doing this, so your best bet would be to use individual profiles (via the Profile Manager) or some other means.

[mauilion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7876/mauilion) is correct, though, that you can (ab)use symbolic links to acheive similar results, but you can only do that between individual sessions - it would be a very bad idea to modify the location of **~/.mozilla** while Firefox is running! (Trust me, I tried that. Firefox wasn't happy about that.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about environment variables. However, you could do some clever work with linking.

Say you wanted the files in `/opt`. As root: `mv /home/$user/.thunderbird /opt/thunderbird`, then link it back in with `ln -sfn /opt/thunderbird /home/$user/.thunderbird`.

You could also do this with an NFS mount or any number of other options.  You can also make a mountpoint in `/etc/fstab` that mounts some remote directory or some local partition to `/home/$user/.thunderbird`.