# overriding HOME location

Tags: home, portability

I'd like to override the user's HOME location locally in a script in order to force an application to store/load its settings portably.

```
export HOME=$TMPDIR/Data
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=$TMPDIR/Data
```

These works in most cases, but there are a few apps that still find the "real" home path.

Why is my method of overriding the user's HOME location not working?

Comment: What are these applications ?

Comment: bsnes, pSX, (possibly others i don't remember now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is highly dependent on what your application is. There are multiple ways that an application can gleam a user's home directory.

1. `$HOME`

   You're already aware of this one. `$HOME` is an environment variable that can be overridden through login config. files such as `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` in a Bash environment. The value is usually something like `/home/username`.
2. `/home/$USER`

   I'd consider this a variant of `$HOME`, but I've encountered applications that foolishly assume that a user's home directory has to be under `/home`, so they tack on the variable `$USER` and use that.
3. parsing `/etc/passwd`

   This is probably the worst offender in terms of the worst way to get a user's home directory but lots of tools and scripts do it this way. Most of them are a variance of something like this where they use the [`getent`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getent) command:

   ```
   $ getent passwd | grep $1 | awk -F: '{ print $6 }'

   # for example (user "saml")
   $ getent passwd | grep saml | awk -F: '{ print $6 }'
   /home/saml
   ```

   The backend "database" that stores the user's info can be anything from the `/etc/passwd` file, to NIS, to an LDAP database.
4. GTK & `g_get_home_dir()`

   The GTK library provides a API, `g_get_home_dir()` which will pull user info from the "passwd" backend rather than use `$HOME`.

   *excerpt from [GLib Reference Manual](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-get-home-dir)*

   > Note that in contrast to traditional Unix tools, this function prefers
   >   passwd entries over the HOME environment variable.
5. KDE

   KDE appears to make use of the $HOME. It will first look for `KDEHOME`
   , falling back to `$HOME/.kde` if that is not set.

   *excerpt [KDE System Administration/KDE Filesystem Hierarchy](http://techbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/KDE_Filesystem_Hierarchy)*

   > This directory tree is, as the name suggests, normally located in the
   >   user's home directory. If this environment variable is not defined,
   >   the default location $HOME/.kde4 is used.

Comment: what about python, java, and mono apps?

Comment: @eadmaster - The technology (python, java, etc.) isn't what controls this. It's like asking why do different C++ applications not use $HOME the same way. It depends on how the programmer implemented their app.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get the current user's home directory.

- One way is to look at the user's passwd entry (in `/etc/passwd`).
- Another way is to look at the `HOME` environmental variable. `$HOME` is actually set from the passwd entry. Applications that may set it include your terminal emulator, your login manager, and sudo.

The applications that you are unable to fool may be looking at the user's passwd entry. It is also possible that they are storing the user's home directory somewhere (possibly as part of an absolute path to some file or directory) and ignoring both `HOME` and the passwd entry.

One way to check if an application uses the `HOME` environmental variable is to grep for it. For example, `grep HOME /usr/bin/pdftex` will return `Binary file /usr/bin/pdftex matches`, meaning `pdftex` might use `$HOME`.

For more definite answers, look through the application's source code.
Use `grep -r 'getenv\s\?(.*HOME'` to speed up the source code analysis a bit.

Comment: Also take a look at [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14944/isnt-home-supposed-to-be-the-location-of-the-users-home-directory?rq=1).